# Отслеживание изменения статуса интернета на c#

Tags: c#

пожалуйста подскажите как отслеживать изменения статуса интернета?(если интернета нет выводить соответствующее сообщение)

Comment: Пинговать какой-то ресурс, например.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25779403)

Answer (score 6):

В операционных системах Microsoft начиная с Windows Vista есть такая функция, как индикатор статуса сетевого подключения (Network Connectivity Status Indicator, NCSI), которая осуществляет две проверки:

- При подключении к сети система посылает HTTP-запрос по адресу http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt. Это обычный текстовый файл, в котором содержится всего одна строка Microsoft NCSI. В случае успешного запроса от сервера должен прийти ответ с заголовком 200 ОК, содержащий эту строку;
- На втором этапе проверяется работоспособность службы DNS, для чего NCSI пытается разрешить в IP-адрес имя dns.msftncsi.com. Ожидаемое значение 131.107.255.255

Вы можете поступить аналогичным образом.

Update. В комментариях предложили импортировать вызов wininet.dll — пожалуй, так будет лучше (чем писать свой велосипед, проще использовать готовое решение).

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll")]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

public static bool CheckNet()
{
     int desc;
     return InternetGetConnectedState(out desc, 0);         
}
```

Comment: индикатор статуса штука прикольная, не знал, но опыт сетевого администрирования подсказывает, что проверять dns надо до запроса к сервису, т.к. запрос как бы уже использует dns. Или там за кадром он напрямую по IP к сервису обращается?

Comment: @rdorn Не, там более простая фишка: это независимые проверки, обе настраиваются отдельно (можно через реестр задать какой адрес, в какой IP резолвится и какой ответ должен быть получен) и обе независимо должны проверяться друг от друга. А вот почему майкрософт решила, что одной проверки мало - это действительно загадка, вероятно какие-то краевые кейсы типа "подмена адресов через hosts"

Comment: а... если настраивается тогда ок. А две проверки потому, что при рабочем dns может быть запрещен http трафик на внешнем файре, что в общем-то наглухо ломает работу некоторых системных служб типа обновления и доставляет неудобства пользователю в браузере, а при нерабочем dns вполне можно работать по IP или резолву через hosts. Так что они обе действительно нужны.